# params.setSkusList(list) doesn't work when list contains more than one sku productId

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

Following code doesn't work

```
                List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
                test.add("product_1");
                test.add("product_2");
                SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
                params.setSkusList(test).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);

                billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                        new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult,
                                                             List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                         
                                    skuDetailsList.size() // size is 0
                                }

                            }
                        });
```

But if I remove `test.add("product_1");` or `test.add("product_2")` line then it gives the skuDetailsList with size 1 with the expected skuDetails object.

so it doesn't work if I add more than one element to the list, how can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Double check the logic inside `setSkusList` function. Probably something going wrong in there.

Comment: @DanielBeleza hello thanks for your comment, but luckily same code started working, not sure how but now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

after waiting for some time and reinstalling the app same code starts working, still not sure what went wrong, and what really worked but if anyone faces this issue

- wait for some time after creating a new SKU product in the google
  play store console
- try clearing cache for google play store and make sure you are signed in to your playstore account

Comment: Clearing cache for google play store worked for me.